# MATLAB GUI is cropped when save

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a problem with the size of MATLAB GUI, I'm using GUIDE to design a large GUI, therefore I changed the size to 1600*1200 by dragging the canvas, but when I save it, the size is automatically changed to around 1360*760, the objects are resized automatically but wrongly, some of them are cropped and some are moved out of the canvas, as shown in the picture. this is happening whether the the GUI is set as resizable or not.
This is how it looks before saving:

[image]

This is how it looks when clicking save:

[image]

I'm using the GUI with a 1080p monitor, is there a way to fix the size of the GUI to 1920*1080 and stop it from shrinking when save? if no, is there a way to make it resize properly when save?

Comment: Okay, the ridiculous fix is to set your monitor resolution, but I think this post sums it up http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/259860 you can use toolboxes suggested to export/print figures, but most of the time the maximum resolution is capped by your monitor display resolution.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the resolution of my display is 1920*1080, I don't know why Matlab cap it by a resolution of 1360*760